# Benefit of interface for getInstance call?

Tags: java, interface

My colleague wrote a code as below for each module.

```
public class ExampleModule {
    interface Holder { // <- watch this
        ExampleModule instance = new ExampleModule ();
    }

    public static ExampleModule getInstance() {
        return Holder.instance;
    }

    public void method1(){
        // do somthing
    }
}

// usage example in other classes after initialization
ExampleModule.getInstance().method1(); // calls like singleton but no?
```

I think *above* code does not intend a `static final`-defined [singleton](https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples) per se.

What about *below* code without `interface`? is it different? Or, does *above* have some benefit than *below* one?

```
public class ExampleModule {
    static ExampleModule instance;

    public static ExampleModule getInstance() {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new ExampleModule();
        return instance;
    }

    public void method1(){
        // do somthing
    }
}
```

Comment: *is it different*: yes. It doesn't compile.

Comment: @JBNizet // let me add `static` to below. sorry.

Comment: The first one is lazy, yours isn't.

Comment: Ah, got it. thanks.

Comment: @JBNizet // and, what could be different in common lazy `if(instance == null)` approach?

Comment: This is explained in all the articles about the singleton anti-pattern (including the one you linked to). Just checking for null is not thread-safe.